# Salesforce DB reserved field names

Tags: salesforce

I have come across some salesforce DB field names like ID, OWNERID etc., which are reserved fieldnames of REFERENCE type. I was searching for some resources where all such types of reserved field names can be found. Would be very much helpful as well as thankful, if somebody can provide some resources or help.

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved"? All field names not ending in `__c` are standard and cannot be created by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a comprehensive list, but you've got:

- [System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm)
- [Frequently-Occurring Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fequently_occurring_fields.htm)
- [Custom Object Standard Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_objectfields.htm&type=5)
- [Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) and their fields

There may be more, but I hope that provides a good start.